# Craft Event Date Range in Craft

Tags: events, queries

I'm creating a date range where I only want to show upcoming events in the next 30 days based on a start date.

I have created my query but when I add my if statement to filter on the start date it doesn't show the upcoming events. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
{% set myEntryQuery = craft.entries()
    .section('events')
    .hidden('not true')
    .orderBy('eventStartDate')
%}

{% set entries = myEntryQuery.all() %}

{% for entry in entries %}
{% set start = entry.eventStartDate | date() %}
{% set currentDate = "now"|date() %}
{% set futureDate = currentDate|date_modify("+30 day")|date() %}


{% if (start >= currentDate) and (start < futureDate) %}
    <item>
        <title>{{ title }}</title>
        <link>{{ url }}</link>
        <pubDate>{{ entry.postDate|rss }}</pubDate>
        <author>CPI</author>
        <guid>{{ url }}</guid>
        <description>
        ---------
            {% if eventType == 'Events' %}
            {% else %}
            {{ eventType }}
            {% endif %}
            {% if start %}
             · {{ start }}
            {% endif %}
            {% if location %}
             · {{ location }}
            {% endif %}
        ---------
        </description>
    </item>
{% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

To debug issues like this, you can put [`{% dd %}` tags](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/tags.html#dd) in your template to inspect the value of variables and find errors in your logic:

```
{% dd currentDate %}
```

The main issue with your template is that you're comparing dates *as formatted strings*. The [`date()` filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/date.html) returns a formatted, human-readable string (so something like *1 January 2021*, the format depends on your locale). Those can't be directly compared, so the `<` / `>` checks fail.

Instead, you want to compare timestamps as `DateTime` objects, which is also the format used by Craft's date fields and properties by default. So removing the `|date` filter from your variables should fix the issue:

```
{% set start = entry.eventStartDate %}
{% set currentDate = now %}
{% set futureDate = currentDate|date_modify("+30 day") %}
```

Note the use of `now` instead of `'now'`. The `now` variable is [provided by Craft](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/global-variables.html#now) and contains the current timestamp as a `DateTime` object.

---

However, instead of fetching all entries and filtering them out afterwards, it would be more efficient to include the acceptable date range as a filter in your query. Something like this should work:

```
{% set futureDate = currentDate|date_modify("+30 day") %}
{% set myEntryQuery = craft.entries()
    .section('events')
    .hidden('not true')
    .orderBy('eventStartDate')
    .eventStartDate(['and', ">= #{now|atom}", "<= #{futureDate|atom}"])
%}
```

See [Querying Elements with Date Fields](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/date-time-fields.html#querying-elements-with-date-fields) for more information.